# Незаполненные поля jinja2

Tags: html, python, jinja2

Вывожу данные в jinja2.

Формат: [{'september_lessons': 7, 'september_spravka': 0, 'september_unattended': 0, 'october_lessons': 7, 'october_spravka': 0, 'october_unattended': 0}]. Объект называется data.

Данные выводятся, но со сдвигом. Создаются дополнительные пустые теги li перед тегами, содержащими данные.

Почему это происходит, как устранить?

```
 <ul class="attended">
        <li class="title">Занятия в сентябре<li>
        {% for dt in data %}
        <li class="lesson">{{ dt['september_lessons'] }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <ul class="unattended">
        <li class="title">Пропущенные в сентябре<li>
        {% for dt in data %}
        <li class="lesson">{{ dt['september_unattended'] }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <ul class="spravka">
        <li class="title">Справки в сентябре<li>
        {% for dt in data %}
        <li class="lesson">{{ dt['september_spravka'] }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Если data такой, какой вы показали, то подобное не может происходить. Составьте [mcve]

Comment: Собственно, вот — пустых li нету: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgvyi.png

Comment: Измените `{%` на `{%-` и посмотрите - поможет или нет.